# R.raw.anything cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse, code-generation

I'm developing an android apps with Eclipse.

In my app, I try to read a file : data.xml. I put it in res/raw/, and to access it i'm supposed to use getRessources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);

But Eclipse show me an error : "data" cannot be resolved or is not a field.

But the field is in the gen/R.java !!!

```
public final class R {
    public static final class raw {
            public static final int data=0x7f040000;
     }
}
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks

---

Solution : 
Import the right R.java files !
     import my_package.R;

Stop trusting ctrl+shift+O ...

Comment: Your are importing the wrong R file. Import your_package.R file instead of android.R file

Comment: have you cleaned the project?  Or restarted eclipse?
if there are Any R. imports, delete them and clean/rebuild -- you should Not import R. of any kind

Comment: Oooo thanks Mojo, it was axactly that !

Comment: This question has so many duplicates, ive been flagging but nothing has happened, maybe more are needed?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I already faced this problem several weeks ago. You simply have to use `com.example.R` (where `com.example` is the name of your package), because your IDE thinks that you are using `android.R` by default.
Try this out.

Answer (score 10):

Try to clean and rebuild your project!

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding does not fix the problem he has with importing the wrong R.

Answer (score 7):

Or just delete `import android.R;`.

Answer (score 2):

If that `data.xml is in raw folder` but still its not resolved once `Clean and build your project and check.`

Still error check this : [Opening raw file](http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/27/using-files-as-raw-resources-in-android/)