# Android: How to add R.raw to project?

Tags: android, resources

How I could add R.raw class to my android project?
Now I haven't /res/raw folder at all (and class as well).
And I can't find any tools in eclipse to do that.
So how to add R.raw?

Comment: Thank you, guys. I've tried simply add raw folder, but it haven't any effect. And then, I don't know what exactly I did, but it worked...

Comment: I think you were importing the wrong R class (at least that was my case).
Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884268/r-raw-anything-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Adding a raw folder to your resource folder (/res/) should do the trick.

Read more here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: What type of file is r.raw.sound? Is it int?

Comment: It's a raw resource which can get accessed by a resource id. (Unlike assets have no resource id) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: The quick answer: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/resource-raw-folder-in-android-studio/

Answer (score 38):

[image]Right click on **package** or **Res folder**  click on **new** on popup then click on android **resource directory**

a new window will be appear change the resource type to **raw** and hit **OK** copy and past song to raw folder 
remember don't drag and drop song file to raw folder and song spell should be in lower case! This method is for Android Studio [Also Check MY Link](https://www.fiverr.com/misbahullahuos/create-develop-an-android-app)

Comment: Note that custom name directory of "raw" type ("ssl" for example) will not be seen in the Project Panel Android View (to the left). Only "raw" is supported on the fly.

Answer (score 25):

If you have a `res/raw` folder, be sure to add a file with a valid filename, otherwise the entire folder won't show up in the R class. If there's an error with a filename, it will appear in red in the console.

Comment: thanks, that did the trick, my mp3 file name was AudioMainAtivity, once removed the upper letters, Eclipse recognised the folder

Comment: Also, don't forget the extension. A file without extension is considered invalid

Answer (score 9):

Simply add a folder 'raw' to your res folder.

Answer (score 5):

The `R` class is written when you build the project in gradle.  You should add the `raw` folder, then build the project.  After that, the `R` class will be able to identify `R.raw.*`.

Answer (score 5):

To get it to recognize the raw file, make sure you create it, and add it as a raw resource file. Then go to **build.gradle** file and add this block of code.

```
sourceSets {
    main {

        assets.srcDirs = ['/res/raw']

    }
}
```

Comment: This will overwrite the other directories.

Answer (score 5):

You may have to restart android studio if above solutions aren't working, i restarted it and then it works.

Comment: Just closing and reopening the project also works!

Answer (score 4):

(With reference to Android Studio)

Create a new directory in res folder. Make sure to create new "Android Resource Directory" and not new "Directory".

Then ensure that there is at least one valid file in it. It should show up now.

Comment: this helped me to solve my issue. It is indeed essential to have a valid file in it

Answer (score 1):

Using IntelliJ Idea:

1) Invalidate Caches, and
2) right click on resources, New Resources directory, type = raw
3) build

note in step 2:  I was concerned that simply adding a raw directory wouldn't be enough...

Comment: Only "Invalidate and restart" worked for me (after I tried all the others advices with no result)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the string to access files in raw folder.
Replace filename with name of your file.

```
android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.filename
```

Answer (score 1):

- You need to right-click on res->new->Android resource directory. Make sure you select directory and not file.
- Select raw in resource type and it automatically selects raw as the directory name.
- Drag and drop your .mp3 music file inside the res folder. Make sure that it starts with a small letter.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `raw` android resource directory.
[image]

Once the raw directory is created, Make sure to add a valid media file

1. Make sure to follow proper naming conventions (lower case letters with underscore '_' as separators)
2. Media file should have a proper encoding and formatted media file in one of the supported formats.

After following the above procedure, you should be able to access your media files by using `R.raw.media_file`

Answer (score 0):

**Right CLick on res folder -> New Android Resource Directory - select resource type raw ->** ok and move your file to this folder

Even if its showing **unresolved reference: raw** in the Android Studio, it does still run. when I did the rebuild it didn't show any error during the build. just put the right path like **R.raw.myrawfile** and run it, the app will run.

if u want the red mark on the code to go away you probably have to restart (do invalidate cache and restart)

Answer (score -2):

Try putting a `+` before `R.xyz`. That should start showing additional folders, e.g.:

```
+ R.raw.beep.mp3
```