# Android Studio create A folder in R.raw

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to create folder in `R.raw` to classify my media source.

But when I try to read the folder in `R`, I can't found the folder.

```
 R.raw.folderName
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691951/android-how-to-add-r-raw-to-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add folders to the `raw` folder or any of the folders inside the `res` folder.

Android supports only a linear list of files within the predefined folders under res. 
The `asset` folder though, can have an arbitrary hyarchie of folders because the `asset` folder is not considered as resources.