# Unable to create media player, short Android app

Tags: android, audio

Very short app, you press a button and play a sound bite. The sounds are in mp3/wav format, the app works on the VM in eclipse but does not when trying it on phone (Galaxy S2).

```
public class SoundBites extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.soundbite);     
    }

    public void SheldonButtonListener(View v){
        MediaPlayer mp_bazinga = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.bazinga);
        mp_bazinga.start();
    }

    public void SpanishButtonListener(View v){
        MediaPlayer mp_spanish = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.spanish_inquisition);
        mp_spanish.start();
    }

    public void NudgeButtonListener(View v){
        MediaPlayer mp_nudge = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.nudge_nudge);
        mp_nudge.start();
    }  
}
```

with xml-file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1.0">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/buttons_helper1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/buttons_helper2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bazinga_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttons_helper1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttons_helper2"
        android:background="@drawable/sheldon_cooper"
        android:onClick="SheldonButtonListener" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/spanish_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttons_helper1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttons_helper2"
        android:background="@drawable/spanish_inquisition"
        android:onClick="SpanishButtonListener" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nudge_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttons_helper2"
        android:background="@drawable/nudge_nudge"
        android:onClick="NudgeButtonListener" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and I get the following error:

```
05-09 20:12:15.395: E/MediaPlayer(15110): Unable to to create media player
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110): create failed:
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:741)
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110):   at com.example.goran.SoundBites.NudgeButtonListener(SoundBites.java:30)
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110):   at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3064)
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3591)
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/MediaPlayer(15110):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-09 20:12:15.405: D/AndroidRuntime(15110): Shutting down VM
05-09 20:12:15.405: W/dalvikvm(15110): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c3e1f8)
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3069)
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3591)
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3064)
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    ... 11 more
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    at com.example.goran.SoundBites.NudgeButtonListener(SoundBites.java:31)
05-09 20:12:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15110):    ... 14 more
```

Tried to google this badboy but have come up empty handed so far, anyone got any ideas? The thing that perturbs me is that it works on the VM but not on my phone.

EDIT: Found two problems, one was that I needed to take control over the Audio Volume, the other one seems to be that my WAV-files are corrupt, made it output the mp3 now at least!

Answer (score 0):

According to this question: [R.raw.anything cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884268/r-raw-anything-cannot-be-resolved)

Eclipse decided to import android.R not your package_name.R file...

**Or**

You need to use your full package name to reference raw resources.

```
    MediaPlayer mp_nudge = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), com.exmaple.goran.R.raw.nudge_nudge);
```

Comment: Hmph, well you are getting a null pointer in those two lines of code.  How do you define R.raw.nudge_nudge? (et al)

Comment: Isn't the null pointer from the media player not being created? As for definition, I just have a file called nudge_nudge.wav in the raw folder.

Comment: Yes, I'm just covering the basics since your code looks fine. Burak KARA has a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Fix Project Properties**. Then cleaning your project!
R wil be generated again.