# Sound file as variable in android MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android

While in the process of learning android/java i wanted to create a function that could play a specefic sound from the raw folder.

I am attempting to define the sound-file as a string, so that the function can be reused.
However i am stuck with "Cannot resolve symbol".

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
MediaPlayer player;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    playSound("dogBark");
}

public void playSound(String soundFile) {
    player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.soundFile); // Cannot resolve symbol 'soundFile'
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.start();

}
...
```

I am sure this is a basic lack-of-knowledge issue, but any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

The above function works well if i add the actual sound file in the function:

```
player = MediaPLayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.dogBark);
```

But what i am trying to do is to define the sound file when i call the function instead:

```
playSound("dogBark");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [R.raw.anything cannot be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884268/r-raw-anything-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: Rebuild your project

Comment: MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier("dogBark", "raw", getPackageName()));
   mPlayer.start();

Comment: Have you tried my solution ? Let me know if anything required.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this way, it works fine for me:

```
playMp3("titanic");
```

Add this method:

```
private void playMp3(String nameOfFile){
   MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier(nameOfFile, "raw", getPackageName()));
   mPlayer.start();
}
```

It would definite work for you.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much

Comment: Please keep in mind to not to try to refer to the file with extension, otherwise the resource ID will not works. Use instead eg. "myString = filename.split("\\.") and then use myString[0] as nameOfFile